# Django post_save signal ( request.COOKIES['device'] )

Tags: django, session, cookies, signals, e-commerce

Currently working on a Django Ecommerce project so I would like to get the cookies of a user from the model I know we use `request.COOKIES['device']` in our view but is there a way to get the cookies in our models part

Comment: Usually the request will not be available in the post_save signal handler. Please share your code where you currently use the cookies and where you want to use them

Comment: the only way to pass data to model is by having a custom property/field in your model so when you save in it your view, you can set the field value = the request cookie device value

Comment: I kind of just set the cookies for new users  by creating mine on the backend then senging it to the frontend using uuid . Thanks a lot